# MYSQL Group Column, Put into DropDown List

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grab a column from a mysql database, the column contains dates which will have duplicate records (200+ per day), which will group them, then to display them in a html drop down form, but then also to link each drop down link to filter all the data by what you select.

I hope that made sense, if not then:

```
Dropdown
---------
2012-7-27 ---> Linked to only show records for this date
2012-7-26 ---> Linked to only show records for this date
etc..
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not even sure this can be done.

Cheers!

Heres what i have so far with getting dates into drop down:

```
<?  $query="SELECT DISTINCT id, date FROM web_leads GROUP BY date";
$DropDownDates = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name=category value=''></option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($DropDownDates)){//Array or records stored in $nt
echo "<option value=$nt[id]>$nt[date]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
?>
```

Comment: anything can be done in Softwares

Answer (score 1):

what you can try is first get the dates in a dropdownlist, then upon click on a particular date run a query

```
 select * from table_name where column_date=date
```

where `date` is the date which was clicked.

Comment: I have no idea how to get a query running upon click, i can see how i want it to act just cant see where to start, i have the dates in a drop down now though at least :)

Answer (score 1):

If your column is of datetime type than you can extract distinct date with following query ::

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(dateColumn) FROM your_table
```

After that when you want to get the records of selected date, pass that selected date from your application & fire the below query ::

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DATE(dateColumn) = 'selected_date'
```

Comment: what your saying makes sense, ive added the code I have for getting the dates into drop down, how i can send the date selected to another query :)

Comment: suppose the id of date dropdown is dateSelect, then use a JS code : var e = document.getElementById("dateSelect");
var selectedDate = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value. Then pass this date from your webpage to your server & there you can write the query above to fetch data.